# How do I use a DropDownList in a Gridview Edit Template when the selected value does not mirror sql data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I am using some dropdowns in a gridview and have been able to convert where the dropdown would say "Monday"(for a bit of user friendliness) to just a simple "1" on insert(so I can easily do sql date time querys). Now I need to be able to do the reverse for the edit template on the gridview. When I hit edit now I get the error "The selected value doesnt exist in the control". I understand that the reason for this is because the value is a `1` instead of `Monday`. Here is my failed attempt to solve the problem:

```
protected void EditFoodItem(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
 string Day = ((DropDownList)gvMainView.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlDay")).SelectedValue;
        switch (Day)
        {
            case "1":
                Day = "Monday";
                break;
            case "2":
                Day = "Tuesday";
                break;
            case "3":
                Day = "Wednesday";
                break;
            case "4":
                Day = "Thursday";
                break;
            case "5":
                Day = "Friday";
                break;
            case "6":
                Day = "Saturday";
                break;
            case "7":
                Day = "Sunday";
                break;
        }
}
```

If the value in the gridview is `1` How can I get the selected value to go to `Monday`...this seems rather simple but it is alluding me

Here is the control

```
<EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDay" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Day") %>' Text='<%# Bind("Day") %>' runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem>Monday</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Tuesday</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Wednesday</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Thursday</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Friday</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Saturday</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Sunday</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </EditItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Where did you write that first block of code?

Comment: @nmat I wrote it in the `onrowediting` event. I edited the code to include it

Comment: Have you tried adding `GridView1.DataBind()` at the end of the method?

Comment: Yes, it does not matter. It still says `SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items`

Comment: Why is `Day` declared inside the method? It should be a property of the class, it needs to be accessible to the markup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do this in code; the `ListItem` has both a `Text` and a `Value` property:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDay" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Day") %>'>
   <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Monday" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Tuesday" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="Wednesday" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="4" Text="Thursday" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="5" Text="Friday" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="6" Text="Saturday" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="7" Text="Sunday" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

The `SelectedValue` will return the day number, and the list will display the day name.

Comment: Your answer reminds me of the K.I.S.S. acronym from my High School days :) thanks for the help! cheers!